# Why get returns 10 items, but paginate returns no items?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

The main problem seems to be with pagination, cause same code with ->get returns some items, but with ->paginate returns nothing.

---

```
$products = DB::table('categories_products')
    ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories_products.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->leftJoin('products', 'categories_products.products_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select('categories_products.categories_id as c_id', 
                'categories.name as c_name', 
                'categories.img as c_img', 
                'categories_products.products_id as p_id', 
                'products.name as p_name', 
                'products.img as p_img');

if(request()->has('category')){
    $products = $products->where('c_id', request('category'));
}

$products = $products->orderBy('p_name')->groupBy('p_id')->paginate(9)
        ->appends(['category' => request('category')]);

dd($products);
```

- Expected result:

  - Items: 10,
  - Pages: 2;
- Code result:

  - items: 0,
  - pages: 1;

---

Changing **paginate->appends** to **->get**:

```
$products = $products->orderBy('p_name')->groupBy('p_id')->paginate(9)
        ->appends(['category' => request('category')]);

dd($products);
```

to

```
$products = $products->orderBy('p_name')->groupBy('p_id')->get();

dd($products);
```

- Returns:

  - items: 10;

Comment: please add code not screen shot

Comment: You aren't going to get any anwsers for this question. Please post your code and the result and the result you are expecting as text.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it working. Had to remove one of the joins.
I think the problem was with SQL selection.
My guess is it didn't like SQL joins or renamed column names.

---

```
    $products = DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('categories_products', 'products.id', '=', 'categories_products.products_id');


    if(request()->has('category')){
        $products = $products->where('categories_id', request('category'));
    }


    $products = $products->groupBy('products_id')->paginate(9)
            ->appends(['category' => request('category')]);


    dd($products);
```